# Get list of Whole Foods Stores using rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I'm trying to use `rvest` to get a list of Whole Foods stores. I've had success using this technique getting information from Wikipedia, FIFA, Yahoo! Finance, etc., but this "table" covers more than one page, but it all has the same url. Sorry, I'm not the best at HTML and don't know the correct name of the type of item in question.

My question: How do I get more than just the first page of data?

Extra Credit: I only need the zip code, which I figured out how to do. If you want to challenge yourself and figure out how to extract the address, that might be helpful! The problem is the Address and City are merged together with no delimiter. I was thinking something like looking for an upper case immediately following a lower case, but there's an instance where the Address ends in an upper case.

Code Below:

```
get_markets <- function() {
    url <- "https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list/state"
    xpath <- '//*[@id="block-views-store-locations-by-state- 
        state"]/div/div/div[3]'
    selector <- "#block-views-store-locations-by-state-state"

    tbl <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(css = selector) %>% # or xpath = xpath
      .[[1]] %>%
      html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
      strsplit('\\s*\\n\\s*') %>%
      unlist() %>%
      .[-c(1:3)] %>%
      matrix(ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE) %>%
      as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(
        zip = stringr::str_extract(V2, "(?<= )\\d{5}(?=U|-)")
      ) %>%
      select(store = V1, zip) %>%
      na.omit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page links at the bottom provide the pages you need to scrape. If you look at the hrefs, they follow a pattern: `https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list/state?page=1`, `state?page=2`, etc., where the first page is `?page=0`, so you can generate the whole list with `paste` and `seq`.

Before scraping, if you look in [the site's robots.txt](https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/robots.txt), it specifies a crawl-delay of 10 seconds, so we'll need to add a `Sys.sleep` call to slow the scraper down.

Strategy-wise, for each page, select all the stores, then use iterate over those nodes and pull out the desired pieces. The address is formatted in multiple `div`s, so calling `html_text` on them separately and collapsing it into a newline-separated string will make it more usable.

Using [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) for iteration (purrr's power with lists and `map_dfr` make it a great complement to rvest),

```r
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

# make URLs
urls <- paste0('https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list/state?page=', 0:22)

# only read first three pages to show concept
pages <- map(urls[0:2], function(url){
    Sys.sleep(10)    # set crawl delay
    read_html(url)
})

# parse pages
stores <- pages %>% 
    map_dfr(function(page){
        page %>% 
            html_nodes('.views-row') %>%    # select store enclosing tags
            map(html_nodes, '.field-content') %>%    # select content nodes for each store
            keep(~length(.x) == 7) %>%    # discard non-store elements
            map_dfr(~list(title = html_text(.x[[2]]), 
                          address = html_nodes(.x[[3]], 'div') %>% 
                              map(html_text) %>% 
                              paste(collapse = '\n'), 
                          phone = html_text(.x[[4]]), 
                          hours = html_text(.x[[5]])))
    })

stores
#> # A tibble: 42 x 4
#>    title          address                  phone  hours                   
#>    <chr>          <chr>                    <chr>  <chr>                   
#>  1 Montgomery     "1450 Taylor Rd\n1450 T… 334.5… 8:00am - 9:00pm seven d…
#>  2 Mountain Brook "3100 Cahaba Village Pl… 205.9… 7:00 am to 10:00 pm. Se…
#>  3 Mobile         "3968 Airport Blvd\n396… 251-2… 8:00 a.m. to 9:00 p.m. …
#>  4 Hoover         "3780 Riverchase Villag… 205-7… 7:00am - 10:00pm Seven …
#>  5 Huntsville     "2501 Memorial Pkwy SW\… 256.8… 8:00am - 9:00pm seven d…
#>  6 Chandler       "2955 West Ray Road\n29… 480-8… "7:00am -10:00pm Seven …
#>  7 Sedona         "1420 West Hwy. 89A\n14… 928-2… 7:00am- Coffee/Juice ba…
#>  8 Scottsdale     "7111 East Mayo Bouleva… 480.5… 7:00am - 10:00pm Seven …
#>  9 Flagstaff      "320 S. Cambridge Lane\… 928-7… 7:00am - 9:00pm Seven d…
#> 10 Tempe          "5120 S. Rural Rd\n5120… 480.4… 7:00am - 10:00pm Seven …
#> # ... with 32 more rows
```

From here, pull the zip code out of the address with regex or an address parser if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Below is my solution. Probably better ones out there:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_url <- function(page) {
  if (page == 0) {
    url <- "https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list/state"
  } else {
    url <- paste0("https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list/state?page=", page)
  }
  return(url)
}

get_last <- function() {
  url <- "https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list/state"
  xpath <- '//*[@id="block-views-store-locations-by-state-state"]/div/div/div[4]/ul/li[11]/a'
  out <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = xpath) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as.numeric()
}

get_markets <- function(page) {
  url <- get_url(page)
  xpath <- '//*[@id="block-views-store-locations-by-state-state"]/div/div/div[3]'
  selector <- "#block-views-store-locations-by-state-state"

  tbl <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(css = selector) %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
    strsplit('\\s*\\n\\s*') %>%
    unlist() %>%
    .[-c(1:3)] %>%
    matrix(ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE) %>%
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(
      zip = stringr::str_extract(V2, "(?<= )\\d{5}(?=U|-)")
      ) %>%
    select(store = V1, zip) %>%
    na.omit()

  return(tbl)
}

markets <- list()

for (i in 1:get_last()) {
  markets[[i]] <- get_markets(i-1)
}
markets <- Reduce(rbind, markets)
```